TypeError: 0, _redux.combineReducers is not a function (it is undefined)
I'm trying to upgrade redux on my react-native project (uses Expo SDK 52) to these versions:
react-redux    8.0.7   ❯  9.1.2
redux          4.2.1   ❯  5.0.1
redux-thunk    2.4.2   ❯  3.1.0

When trying to run the app in Expo Go, I run into the following error:
TypeError: 0, _redux.combineReducers is not a function (it is undefined)
Here's the store setup - it works perfectly with all current versions (redux 8). The file path is src/ducks/store.js:
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // list of reducers here
});

export default createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

I've only found a recommendation to remove node_modules and reinstall which does not help. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm having the same issue: TypeError: 0, _redux.combineReducers is not a function (it is undefined) My project is using react-native: 0.76.3 and @reduxjs/toolkit: 2.4.0. Has anyone else faced this or found a solution?

Thunk is a named export now in v3, i.e. import { thunk } from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { thunk } from 'redux-thunk';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // list of reducers here
});

export default createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

But you really ought to be using Redux-Toolkit now anyway so you can write modern Redux from this decade. RTK includes the Thunk middleware by default. createStore from redux is also marked deprecated.
Review Migrating to Modern Redux for complete details.
Using Redux-Toolkit:
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // list of reducers here
});

export default configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
});


I've actually tried using configureStore and I'm facing the same kind of error: TypeError: 0, _redux.configureStore is not a function (it is undefined) . Neither using thunk as a named export helps at this point.

@VladimirI Think you could create a running CodeSandbox demo of the code (and versions) you are using that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?
